# Azure server access a port

Tags: azure, server, ubuntu-14.04, port, kibana

I have ELK set up on Azure Ubuntu 14.04 server, which working fine before.
Recently, the server is full and kibana is down, so i have to install Curator to delete the old indices.

The problem is after that (I dont know what I did), the Kibana is not accessible from outside the server.

In the server, `curl MY_IP:5601` works, but outside the server, showing `operation time out`, so kibana not working anymore.

My elasticsearch:

`lsof -i:9200`
[image]

My kibana service:

[image]

It's so annoying, since it's working before and suddenly doesn't work anymore.

This is the Azure NSG rules

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer myself, I was under the wifi of university, which blocks all the custom ports of TCP connections.